# Assigning table column width w/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table. The first column contains labels. The rest of the columns contain values. I do not know how many columns can there be but I would like to make all but the first column the same width.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So, I know the table width

```
var tW = $("#myTbl").width();
```

I can get the width of the first column:

```
var fcW = $("#myTbl th:first").width();
```

Now i need to find how many columns are there in the table, subtract the width of the first column from the table width and divide the rest by the (number of cols - 1).

How do I find the number of columns?

Tried but failed

```
var nimCol = $("#myTbl th:first").parent().find("th").length - 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a complete working example of what, "I think," you're looking for...

http://jsfiddle.net/UXwWe/

```
<table style="width:200px">
<tr>
    <th style="width:40px"></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var table = $('table'),
            tWidth = table.width(),
            firstColumnWidth = table.find('th:first').width(),
            cols = table.find('th').not(':eq(0)'),
            colWidth = (tWidth - firstColumnWidth) / cols.size();

        cols.width(colWidth);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to obtain the column count just by checking how many table headers (`<th>` elements) there are. This will do that:

```
var colCount = $('#myTbl th').length;
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/consultcory/sE4HE/).